# Socket receives the correct bytes, bytes translate to empty string

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I've been breaking my head over a bug in this system I've been building. Basically, I use sockets to communicate between two C# applications. Or rather a Unity C# script server and a C# client application.

With manual tests, the system works perfectly fine, no anomalies whatsoever.
In order to test performance and multi-user functionality, I wrote up a tester class which launches multiple threads(clients), and have those fire X amount of messages at the server. Here's where my problem occurs...Sometimes.

When a Socket sends or receives, it returns an integer container the amount of bytes that was sent/received. When the problem occurs, I can see that the correct amount of bytes arrived at the server. However, after putting the bytes into a string, suddenly I'm left with an empty string, instead of the message I'd normally see here.

I'm at a loss at to what's causing this problem. I'm using Encoding.Default.GetString() to translate the bytes into a string.

Any help is appreciated!
David

```
public void ReceiveFromClient (Socket handlerSocket)
{
    serverBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize]; //iBufferSize = 8192;

    int i = handlerSocket.Receive (serverBuffer);
    Debug.Log ("Bytes received: " + i);

    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (serverBuffer, 0, i);
    Debug.Log ("Message received: " + message);

    //Do stuff with the message
```

}

```
bool SendMessageToUnity(string input)
    {//returns a bool saying whether the message was sent or not
        if (clientSocket != null)
        {  
            if (clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input+"|");
                txtOutput.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txtOutput.AppendText("Sending message: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) + Environment.NewLine)));

                int i = clientSocket.Send(bytes);
                txtOutput.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txtOutput.AppendText("Sending "+i+" bytes. "+ Environment.NewLine)));
                return true;
            }                
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You should use `Encoding.UTF8`, not `Encoding.Default`. `Encoding.Default` can be different between different computers.

Answer (score 0):

Look for for a zero value ('\0') in your array of bytes before converting it to a string.

```
private string GetString(byte[] data)
{
  data = data.Where(b => b != 0).ToArray();
  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
```

Comment: I took a look and this doesn't seem to be the problem, there's no zero value in the bytes I'm looking at right now, but it did translate to an empty string. I did notice something else though. When I get an empty string, the amount of bytes I have exceeds the number of bytes the Receive function says was sent. I have an array with positions 0 - 27 filled, but it's saying it only received 26 bytes. I do refresh my byte array before each Receive.

Comment: Please post your code. if you are calling the Receive overload of Socket class with offset parameter make sure that your are passing zero for offset.

Comment: Your code looks fine, can you please post the code that is responsible of sending data

Comment: Your methods are working correctly, You better check their input parameters. input string passed to SendMessageToUnity method might not be exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the byte array correctly than the problem in the Encoding.
Check the sending Encoding usually UTF8 but you have to check it out.

and then var inputStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(InputByteArray);

^^